# How to say "welcome to" in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I've seen the questions and answers about "welcome", and I haven't seen anything about  "Welcome to". Then I decided to search on the OLD, and I saw the adjective "acceptus" for people. We can use it with the Dative:
"Si tibi ambo accepti sumus"
With  Apud: "essetne apud te is servos acceptissimus?"
And with Ad: "NEC AD DEOS NEC AD HOMINES ACCEPTUS EST"
Ok. The problem is that I couldn't understand if we can use these three options to say that someone is welcome to some place.
What preposition should I use?

Comment: Hmm I would say, why not? When someone is welcome to a place, that really means the people of the place feel that he is welcome there. Being accepted (in)to a place, that sounds fine and pretty much aequivalent to me. But I don't have any quotations on hand. Is there a specific context in which you wanted to use this? As an invitation, perhaps something like "intra!" or "veni!" might be good?

Comment: @Cerberus I just wanted to know "welcome to" we can say "welcome to my house"(a place)"welcome to my life"(not a place)etc. When we're talking about places, I believe we can use the accusative+ad,in or absolute, even though I can't see any motion in "welcome to". I saw "salvus(a) sis" as "welcome!"[and this is very similar to the portuguese expression "Seja bem-vindo(a)]in the only English-latin dictionary I have, but nothing about "welcome to".

Comment: I think "welcome to" is an idiomatic expression that exists in the modern languages, but which would probably be expressed by a different idiom in Latin anyway. So I don't think there is a need to focus on this particular phrase: just think about the purpose of the statement, and then think about how that could be expressed without this particular idiom.

Comment: @Cerberus Since I speak portuguese, and there's the "salvus(as) sis" which is very similar to the portuguese expression, I believe I can use that. Now I have to unbrush my knowledge of the accusative case. :)

Comment: Sounds good to me. Note that *salvus* means "healthy", so the origin of the expression is, "may you be healthy/well".

Comment: @Cerberus I see some sense in this. Haha